# Continued filtering/querying on a group by into object?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below query which returns a list of `Registrations` grouped by `CourseId's`.

```
var coursesTest = (from r in db.Registrations
                     group r by r.CourseId into distinctCourses
                     select distinctCourses).ToList();
```

I want to continue to query and filter down with something like this;

```
var coursesTest = (from r in db.Registrations
                   group r by r.CourseId into distinctCourses
                   from dc in distinctCourses
                   where dc.CourseName != null
                   select new
                   {
                       name = dc.CourseName,
                       Id = dc.CourseId
                   }).ToList();
```

When I do this, I now get the full record set of `Registrations`... why?

Comment: What did you expect to get from your query?

Comment: A distinct list of courses with CourseId and CourseName where CourseName always has a value.  This is a made up example.  The larger question is, can I query the distinctCourses further?  If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wonder why can't you do it? Try to do it in SQL the way you're trying to do it at the moment. You can't select members that aren't specified inside group by or aren't part of an aggregate function.

This part `from dc in distinctGroups` acts like `.SelectMany` which breaks your grouping all over again. That's why you get all members instead of them being grouped. You can see the way it works if you open your dll after it's compiled. I made an example here, this is basically how it looks after compile:

[image: ILDASM]

If you want to select specific properties from your objects then you need to group by both of them inside your `group by` part like this:

```
var coursesTest = (from r in registrations
                   where r.CourseName != null
                   group r by new { r.CourseId, r.CourseName } into distinctCourses
                   select distinctCourses.Key).ToList();
```

Property `Key` will contain anonymous type object you created inside `group by` case and it will be grouped properly.

**EDIT:**

Further explanation:

This is Linq interpretation of SQL and it acts the same way. I'm not sure how much are you familiar with SQL, but when you're writing a query that has a group by, you can't `SELECT` anything that isn't part of your group by or is part of an aggregate function. For example `COUNT(*)`, `SUM(Something)` etc. In C# Linq version, when you write `group <item> by <property(ies)> into <newGroup>`, that `newGroup` has `Key` property that automatically contains all elements that you can possibly select and those are the ones you used inside your `group by`. What you can do further with it is only to add some aggregate functions beside those properties.

Some visual examples:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfCourses, CourseId, CourseName
FROM dbo.Courses
WHERE CourseName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY CourseId, CourseName
```

It's the same as this:

```
var result =
    (from c in Courses
     where c.CourseName != null
     group c by new { c.CourseId, c.CourseName } into groupedCourses
     select new { c.Key, NumberOfCourses = c.Count() }).ToList();
```

So, once again, `group by` `Key` contains all possible properties you can get from initial course `c` and those are the ones you used in `group by`. You can either use it to expand it further by some aggregate functions over the collection you now have or to get them all back as a result.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I'm not sure I completely understand the '.Key' but this is what I was after.  If you have the time to explain, I'd love to understand.  My question is, why can I iterate through object.properites in the simple solution above whereas when grouped by, I can't without the '.Key'?  Is it because .Key creates an index in the annonymous object?  Newb question I know but that's why I'm on here ;)

Comment: @JReam Edited, hopefully I explained it better now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need something like this (all courses whose grouping doesn't have any items with `CourseName` equal to `null`:

```
var set = db.Registrations.GroupBy(v => v.CourseId)
    .Where(x => x.All(y => y.CourseName != null))
    .SelectMany(z => z)
    .Select(a => new { Name = a.CourseName, Id = a.CourseId });
```

If you just want all the `Registration` objects with a non-null `CourseName`, then why would you group them in the first place? Just filter the original list.

Comment: I'm attempting to normalize data from a csv import.  I want to extract distinct course id's and course names from the registration dataset to add to a course table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var coursesTest = (from r in db.Registrations
                   group r by r.CourseId into distinctCourses
                   select distinctCourses)
                  .Select(c => new { Id = c.Key, CourseNames = c.Where(x => x.CourseName != null) });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is my normal approach.  I'm trying to figure out how to do it all in one query though.

Comment: @JReam ... Check my updated answer.it is now in one query. :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems overly complicated for something so simple:

```
var coursesTest = db.Registrations
  .Where(r=>r.CourseName!=null)
  .Select(r=>new {r.CourseId,r.CourseName})
  .Distinct()
  .ToList();
```

Comment: This is the solution I originally had.  However, in cases where there's more fields, your solution checks the distinct combination of all the fields.  Therefore if you had a third field, say, CourseLocation; if CourseID and CourseName were the same on two records, but CourseLocation differed, then you'd have the course listed twice.  This has been my findings but I'm new to this so I defer this true false statement to those more qualified.

Comment: Yes, then you would need to group them.

Comment: gave you a vote because your answer does accomplish this use case.  thanks for explaining!

Comment: I would suggest, as you are learning that you grab this https://www.linqpad.net/ and play with it.  It'll answer most of your questions for you as you try different queries and you see what you get as a result.  It is really helpful to be able to visually see the results of your queries, or portions of your queries as you build it up.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
var coursesTest = (from r in db.Registrations
                 group r by r.CourseId into distinctCourses
                 select distinctCourses).Where(r=>r.dc.CourseName != null).ToList()
```

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think the reason is to do with the LINQ sequence. In my (limited) experience better to retrieve your dataset and then filter it with a Where constraint at the end

Comment: Can you explain why the second `from` in the questioner's query syntax behaves the way it does? I understand your switching to lambda syntax will probably fix the problem, but it would be great if we could understand the root cause.

Comment: This solution just filters a bit more but does not return just the course id and name paired values that are distinct in the registrations dataset.

Comment: As I said I am not an expert, newb here, but it looks to me like it's a second query to which the original where constraint did not apply where it was placed originally. I'm sure there are wiser folks on here who explain it more precisely

Comment: Someone else down voted, not me.  Thanks for posting, I'm a newb too.  I usually take a process 1, process 2 approach, but I'm trying to improve my queries so that there's less roundtrips to the db.

Comment: It may help to note the SQL execution sequence which has an impact here. It's FROM clause
WHERE clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
SELECT clause
ORDER BY clause

Comment: @ JReam. No worries. Unfortunately, it's not a very friendly place for new participants who are only learning!

Comment: I've taken a lot on the chin over the last 8 months of being on this site.  Some are helpful, some like to show off what they know.